# Announcement: some changes to "migration"

Tags: discussion, migration

For those who do not visit Meta.StackOverflow regularly, there is a recent change in software on how Question Migrations are handled.

In particular: **[we can no longer migrate questions older than 60-days old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days)**. The only case to be made for migrating older questions is if a **[newly graduated site now better covers the subject area which previously fell under our scope](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152597/how-to-migrate-old-questions-to-a-new-graduated-site)**. (For example, think of when Mathematica.SE or SciComp.SE came into being.) In that case the questions have to be both *requested* by the receiving site and also proposed by the giving site. (See the above links for details.)

*How does this change how we handle questions on this site?*

Not much, fortunately. We have always been fairly permissive about what falls under Mathematics (see our [FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq)). The main impact that I foresee is that occasionally we would see migration requests for old questions that remained on this site for a while unanswered, and now has probably a better home. Previously we would just deal with them silently. But now we would have to follow the procedure above.

Comment: Is this "Announcement Week", or just "Announcement Day"? Why wasn't an announcement for this issued to the meta? And also is this going to be a yearly thing? :-)

Comment: For the first two: dunno. It could be one, another, or neither. You jest for the third. For the fourth, that kinda depends on [what we get in our newsletters](http://moderator.stackexchange.com/); the most recent one which prompted the two announcements I made has not yet been posted there. But will be in some time.

Comment: The whole comment was a jest. :-)