# I found MO has been included in SE network today

Tags: discussion, mathoverflow, cross-posting

Is it okay to cross post questions on MO and MSE anymore?

How about ask a question on MSE after posting on MO but not getting answers, or vice versa?

Comment: IIRC the OP can request migration (which might be a reasonable way to do, if he does not get any answers). See the discussion here: [What, when and will we migrate questions to MO 2.0?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4880/what-when-and-will-we-migrate-questions-to-mo-2-0)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Wow...the migration almost took a year.

Comment: Closer to two years, actually!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Short answer : **no**.

(By the way, it has never been "okay" to simultaneously cross-post questions on MSE and MO. We've been requesting users to stick with one site and wait for a reasonable amount of time before trying to ask on the other site.)

Longer answer: As of today, a question that you may want to move between the two fora now can be properly migrated! The usual rules apply (only questions less than <strike>a month</strike> [two months old](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6818/announcement-some-changes-to-migration) can be migrated directly, other requires intervention of a higher power).

Comment: As a side remark: because of the high overlap of users between the two sites, it is quite likely that a cross post will be noticed and then migrated and then closed as duplicate...

Comment: Stupid question: How can I migrate my question to MO?

Comment: @RobertRauch Flag for moderator attention and state so - there is no migration path yet so you can't manually select MO as the desired migration destination. Mods can migrate to any SE site though